# How to assign id property to mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to add `id` property to `mat-select`?

I have tried:

```
<mat-select id="mat-select-{{example.id}}">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let u of users" [value]="u.id">
        {{u.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

but I cannot retrieve the element using `document.getElementById('mat-select-10')`, it returns null.

Comment: Why do want to retrive element ?

Comment: Perhaps are you calling `document.getElementById` before the view is rendered? Such as, in the constructor for your component?

Comment: Also you should inspect the DOM and see what the ID value for that `mat-select` is

Comment: To retrieve/set values. I created several of them dynamically and I could not find another way to retrieve or set the selected values.

Comment: I have some `input` fields and they are working fine.

Comment: Have you checked angular forms https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview?

Comment: I solved my problem using FormGroup and FormBinder. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your requirement clearly but I think you want a unique id to be associated with the dropdown values coming in the mat select component. If that is correct this is the stackblitz that you can follow

[Mat select example with dynamic ids](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gehxwd-uphoev?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

To give you an overview, in the mat-option you need to set the id property like this:

```
<mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" [id]="food.value">
       {{food.viewValue}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

If you will inspect the element you will find the dynamic associated with the DOM element. Hope it helps.

Comment: I would like to set a unique id for each `mat-select`, not with the dropdown values.

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate your prefix `mat-select` with your dynamic name as this:

```
<mat-select id="'mat-select-' + {{example.id}}">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let u of users" [value]="u.id">
        {{u.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```